# How to represent 4 bit integers properly?

Tags: r

I need to convert a matrix to a hex file output. Each entry in the matrix needs to get translated to a 4 bit hex digit (8) and output in a single dimension array.

```
> matrix(c(0,0,0,5,0,0,5,5,0,0,5,0),nrow=3,ncol=4,byrow=T)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    0    0    0    5
[2,]    0    0    5    5
[3,]    0    0    5    0
```

This is a 3 row, 4 column matrix with mostly 0s and some 5s. My desired output should be something similar to

```
#> as.raw(c(0,8,0,136,0,128))
> as.raw(solution)
[1] 00 08 00 88 00 80
```

I was trying to do some simple

```
> sidewaysraw<-as.raw(ifelse(mymat==5, 8,0))
```

but the 8 in the ifelse of course is a 16 bit integer, so it's always an 0x08. I don't see a slick way to translate 55s to 0x88s, 05s to 0x08s and 50s to 0x80s...

Is there a smooth way to get R to work with 4 bit integers?

Comment: Why does your `0m55` get converted to `0x88`? Shouldn't it be  `0x37`?

Comment: 55 has two 5s, so it needs to get translated to two 8s to conform to the legacy software.

Comment: Okay. So you basically want to split each row into chunks of 2 and then replace every `0m5` with an `0x8` if I got you correctly?

Comment: You make it sound so simple! I don't recognize the 0m notation, but each 8 bit character in the matrix (5s in this example) need to get converted to a 4 bit 0x8.So far I'm coming up blank on how to make a 0x8, because as.raw(0x8) turns into an 08. Thanks for looking!

Comment: `0mXXX` just stands for `XXX` is formatted in decimal notation. The same as `0xXXX` stands for `XXX` is formatted in hexadecimal notation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming I understood your question correctly, this solves your problem:

```
mat <- matrix(c(0,0,0,5,0,0,5,5,0,0,5,0),nrow=3,ncol=4,byrow=T)
mat_new <- matrix(t(mat),ncol=2,byrow=T) #reformat to 2 columns
vec <- apply(mat_new,1,function(row)
{
  num <- paste0(row,collapse="") #collapse the rows
  if(num == "00") return(as.raw(0)) #switch the resulting char
  else if(num == "05") return(as.raw(8))
  else if(num == "50") return(as.raw(128))
  else if(num == "55") return(as.raw(136))
})

vec
[1] 00 08 00 88 00 80
```

Comment: Great solution! Easy to understand, no intricate funny syntax, thank you!

Comment: D'oh, broke the reformat step with an odd number of cells (5x5).

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you could do some matrix multiplication to help. First we can define a "translation matrix"

```
digits <- matrix(c(128,8,0,0,0,0,128,8), nrow=4, ncol=2)
```

Then you can get your numbers out with

```
(dd==5) %*% digits
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    0    8
# [2,]    0  136
# [3,]    0  128
```

and then extract them in the right order with a transposition

```
as.raw(t((dd==5) %*% digits))
# [1] 00 08 00 88 00 80
```

This should be efficient and doesn't bother with string manipulation.

Comment: As cool as this is, I don't understand how the translation matrix works. Can you explain that part?

Comment: It's just matrix multiplication. You weight each column of your original matrix by the value of the digit in the binary representation.

Comment: Very nice solution. Generalizes much better than my quick and dirty one.